# Java: Deserialize object with list of Objects

Tags: java, jackson, mapstruct

I have this JSON: (passed as `Map<String, Object>`)

```
{
  "id": 1000,
  "lab": [
    "LAB1",
    "LAB2",
    "LAB3"
  ],
  "name": "TEST",
  "ref": {
    "id": 1000,
    "code": "REFCODE",
    "description": "REF DESC"
  },
  "employee": {
    "id": 1000,
    "name": "Emp1000",
    "tin": null,
    "active": true
  },
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": 1000,
      "name": "Contact 1",
      "emailAddress": "contact1@test.com",
      "active": true,
      "positions": [
        {
          "position": {
            "id": 1000,
            "code": "POS",
            "description": "POS DESC"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "NEW"
}
```

This is my DTO and ContactDTO:

```
public class DTO {
    private Long id;
    ...

    @JsonProperty("contacts")
    private List<ContactDTO> contacts; 

}

@Builder
public class ContactDTO implements Serializable {    
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String emailAddress;
    private Boolean active;
    @NotEmpty
    private List<ContactPositionDTO> positions;
}
```

Here is my service class with object mapper and process method which accepts the JSON map:

```
private ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    // objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
    return objectMapper;
}

public void process(final Map<String, Object> map) {
    objectMapper().convertValue(map, DTO.class);
}
```

However, I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize value of type java.util.ArrayList`

And if I add `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` I am getting a different error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance of ContactDTO (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('[{id=1000, name=Contact 1, .....`

Comment: Your json is invalid.

Comment: Posting a question that is fully JSON related, then adding ... to it, defeats the entire purpose.

Comment: Also, why is your date broken up into an array...here's your sign :)

Comment: updated the json. the date uses localdate. even if i removed it and just use id and name in my contacts json, I still encounter the same error.

Comment: Pretty sure I already found it...but thank you for that, i'll retract my closure.

Answer (score 0):

You have two alternative options to fix your `ContactDTO` class:

- Add a no-arguments constructor
  `public ContactDTO() { }`
  to the class. To fix the then upcoming compiler error
  you will need to remove the `@Builder` annotation.
- Keep the `@Builder` annotation
  and add the `@Jacksonized` annotation to the class.
  This will configure the generated builder to cooperate
  with Jackson's deserialization.
  For more details see [Lombok's documentation about `@Jacksonized`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized).

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize you need a No arg constructor and to use `@Builder` you need an all arg constructor.
So you need tu add both.
The example below should work. I just added `@Getter` annotation to avoid using `@JsonProperty`

```
@Getter
public static class DTO {

    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("contacts")
    private List<ContactDTO> contacts;
}

@Builder
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class ContactDTO implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String emailAddress;

    private Boolean active;

    private List<ContactPositionDTO> positions;
}

@Getter
public static class ContactPositionDTO {

    private Position position;

    @JsonProperty("effectiveStartDate")
    private List<Integer> date;

    @Getter
    static class Position {

        private Integer id;

        private String code;

        private String description;
    }
}
```

NB: you can also use `@Jacksonized` annotation instead of `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor`